# React change state triggers transition

Tags: css, reactjs, transition

I have the following react component

```
export interface IDivBodyVisible {
    isVisible: string;
}

export default class NavDropDownItem extends React.Component<{ItemContent: string}, IDivBodyVisible> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
        isVisible: 'none' 
    }
}


render() {
         return (
            <div className="divBox" >
                <div className="divHeader" onClick={this.SwitchVisibility}>
                    <Icon className="icon"  iconName="ChevronDown"/>
                    {this.props.ItemContent}
                </div>
                {
                    this.state.isVisible !== 'block' ? null :
                <div className="divBody">
                    <ul className="ItemList">
                        <li>
                            <a className="miau" title="item1" onClick={this.ConsoleLog}>Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a title="item2" onClick={this.ConsoleLog}>Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a title="item3" onClick={this.ConsoleLog}>Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
         )
}


private ConsoleLog = () : void => {
    console.log("Test");
}

private SwitchVisibility = (): void => {
    this.setState({
        isVisible : this.state.isVisible === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
    });
 }
}
```

At the moment if I click on the icon, the divbody appears instantly. Instead, I want that the divbody slights very smooth. I already tried to give the .divBox a transition ease-out 0.2, but that didn´t do anything.

Is there any advice what I can try?

Comment: This sounds more like a question related to `CSS` and you don't show any `CSS` code at all.

Comment: did you try to add delay? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Comment: @goto1 yeah, i thought the same way, but i am not sure about it. As i mentioned i already tried this:

.divBody{
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;   
    border-color: black;
    border-width: thin;
    transition: ease-out 0.2;
}

Comment: @Sodhisaab yes, i added it to **.diBody/.divBox** tried both

Comment: Its better to create a fiddle ( which reproduces your issue ) than 1000 likes of dead code  ;)